# Actualización de decimales en NestJS y TypeORM

Tags: mysql, typescript, backend, nestjs, typeorm

Tengo una función que consiste en actualizar una orden tanto el encabezado (header) como el detalle agregando algún producto nuevo, mi problema es que me retorna, que se ejecuta la función bien, estoy usando el try/catch, pero no me captura ningún tipo de error, también estoy usando transacciones en NestJS, pero no me reconoce ningún tipo de error en la ejecución, por lo tanto, me dice que todo se ejecutó bien, pero cuando veo los cambios en la base de datos me agrego la modificación a la tabla de detalle, pero no me actualiza los totales del encabezado:

Este es mi código en OrderService.ts:

```
async update(id: number, changes: any) {
        try {
            const result = await this.connection.transaction(
                async (transactionalEntityManager) => {
                    const options = {
                        where: {
                            id,
                        },
                    }

                    const orderHeader =
                        await this.orderRepository.findOne(options)

                    if (!orderHeader) {
                        throw new NotFoundException('Order not found')
                    }

                    // console.log('Header', orderHeader)
                    // console.log('Changes', changes)

                    const order = {
                        iva: Number(changes.iva),
                        subtotal: Number(changes.subtotal),
                        total: Number(changes.total), // Convert the total to a number
                    }

                    // Operación 1: Merge
                    await this.orderRepository.merge(orderHeader, order)

                    // Operación 2: Eliminar todos los detalles de la orden
                    await this.orderDetailsService.removeAllItems(
                        orderHeader.id,
                    )

                    // Operación 3: Actualizar detalles de la orden
                    for (const itemOrder of changes.detalle_orden) {
                        itemOrder.orden_id = orderHeader.id
                        itemOrder.producto_id = itemOrder.producto.id
                        await this.orderDetailsService.create(itemOrder)
                    }
                },
            )

            return result
        } catch (error) {
            throw new BadRequestException(error.message)
        }
    }
```

Esta es la estructura de la tabla de ordenes en mi base de datos:

```
CREATE TABLE `ordenes` (
  `id` int NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `subtotal` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `total` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  `iva` decimal(10,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=236 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

Y mi entidad de TypeORM es esta:

```
import {
    Column,
    Entity,
    PrimaryGeneratedColumn,
} from 'typeorm'

@Entity({ name: 'ordenes' })
export class Order {
    @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
    id: number

    @Column({ type: 'decimal' })
    subtotal: number

    @Column({ type: 'decimal' })
    iva: number

    @Column({ type: 'decimal' })
    total: number
}
```

Ya lo he probado de diferentes maneras, con la transacción y sin la transacción y sigo con el problema de que no me actualiza el encabezado de la orden, si alguien me puede ayudar detectando si me falta algo o algún error que estoy cometiendo, se lo agradecería mucho

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya lo he solucionado:

Agregandole el metodo .save del repositorio luego de hacer el .merge

```
await this.orderRepository.merge(orderHeader, order)
await this.orderRepository.save(orderHeader)
```